# Laptop unusable after deleting /bin

Tags: directory-structure

For a long time I've been wanting to get into Linux so I asked my friend if I could borrow his laptop (he's running Ubuntu).

I was playing with it for a while and getting used to it, I saw his recycling bin (/bin/) had 7MB of stuff in it so I thought I might empty it and now I can't open any programs, I'm scared to restart it now. What should I do? He has all of his school work on it.

Comment: Are the files in the `trash can` in the lower left corner of the "start menu?"  Can you open the `trash can` and `restore` the files?

Comment: [Assuming this is real] The owner is either running with root access or changed the permissions on /bin. Either way, he screwed up.

Comment: The owner is far more likely to be able to recover the system than the OP is. Assuming this is genuine, my advice would be to (a) leave the laptop powered on, (b) **do not touch anything**, and (c) tell the owner exactly what happened.

Answer (score 6):

When you "emptied the recycle bin" what you actually did was delete most of the binary programs from his computer.  You have basically bricked him laptop... How you did that without it asking for a password and you not wondering "hmmmm, should I be deleting files I don't know if my friend may need again" is beyond me. But I regress.

Go ahead and turn it off, it will NOT boot again but leaving it on will not help at all as there are no programs you can run that will allow you to do anything useful.  What you will need to do is use a liveCD such as `Ubuntu Resuce Remix`  which can be found [here](http://ubuntu-rescue-remix.org/).

You could also use a normal Ubuntu liveCD as well but the rescue CD may make it a little easier.  You will need some `CDs`, `DVDs` or a usb drive to put the files on while you re-install the `OS` and then you can restore his files.  Or if he has another partition you could move all of the files there while you restore the OS.  I would highly recommend you tell him what you did and get his help before you make it any worse and just flat out delete all of his data.

Good Luck!

Comment: I'm sure it's too late now (assuming this is genuine), but `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are two separate directories in Ubuntu. It's at least possible that there are programs under `/usr/bin` that could be used to restore the contents of `/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

You removed the programs from his computer.

/bin does not mean "trashbin"
/bin means "binaries" as in the executable version of programs.

Do not restart the computer.  Most likely it wont boot since the default shells are in /bin.

If you do turn the computer off you'll need to pull out the HDD to pull any files off of it.

http://www.linfo.org/bin.html

Comment: Why does he have to pull out the HD? What do you suggest he do before restarting?  I would suggest using `cp` to move the files somewhere safe or to restore the files in `bin` but that command was deleted.

Comment: From what I can tell, the person asking the question has a minimalistic understanding of how a Linux system works.  So my suggestion was made because a new user can understand pull out the hard drive and then copy the files you want from it off.  I could have told him to boot from a live disk, mount the HDD, then use `cp` to copy the contents of the live disks `bin` directory to the root level to replace the one he/she removed but gathering that he/she didn't understand what /bin was I chose to provide an easy to use solution.

Comment: I see your point, I guess I had the same view in that using a screw driver to remove the cover off of a laptop, locating the hard drive, removing the mount screws trying to slide the hard drive out just enough to remove the power and sata sables but to too far to pull on them then taking the hard drive to an unknown location that has a free power and sata cable and mounting the drive and coping what you needed is harder than downloading a file, burning a CD, putting the CD into the other computer, pressing F10 while it starts and following on screen guides sounded easier...

Comment: well when you put it like that =P.  I understand your point though.  Both ways work, it just depends on the resources available to you.  I forget that not everyone has another computer and extra sata cables/external HDD bays available.

Comment: I would have used your method personally but from a new user point of view I think the other method might have been easier... Both work. I just hope this person admits defeats and asks his friend for help... I also wonder if the `/bin` files were put into the `trash can` and he could just restore them and copies of `cp` and other used programs are stored in `ram` I don't know enough of the internal workings.  I might try just for fun...

Comment: I once read an article about rebuilding a Linux system after executing `rm -rf /`.  I believe the outcome was if you had the right programs still in memory it was possible to restore the entire system.

Comment: @Dylan  I think this was it [here](https://lambdaops.com/rm-rf-remains/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22641/discussion-between-rnikoopour-and-dylan).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to re-install the OS. You just need to replace the bin files that were in /bin. In theory you might even be able to recover from this without shutting down the computer since most of your core programs are still loaded in memory, but it might be easier to use a LiveCD.

Probably the easiest way to recover is to get the installation media for the distribution, and copy everything in the bin directory from the installation media onto the /bin directory on the laptop.

That said, I don't know how you would delete the /bin directory on your friends laptop unless you knew what you were doing, and unless /bin was symlinked to /usr/bin (as in archlinux), then you probably wouldn't have even noticed the problem until you restarted your computer after deleting /bin, since user applications are in /usr/bin and important programs in /bin would already be in memory. Finally, if you weren't already familiar with linux or unix, I don't know why you would link deleting /bin (what you thought was the trash bin) to bricking the computer (or why you would empty your friends trash can in the first place). Therefore I doubt the authenticity of the question.